# xfce crashes on launch of applications

Tags: xfce, crash, application

I am running openSUSE Tumbleweed and would like to use xfce as my desktop environment. GNOME works flawlessly, but I am having a big problem with xfce.

The problem is that xfce crashes on the launch of certain applications such as  Firefox, Dragon Player, and others. When I attempt to launch one of these applications, I get a blank black window and xfce freezes. I can only get out using ctrl-alt-backsp. The strange thing is that after I execute that key combination, I momentarily see the desktop as it really should be, e.g. Firefox with my home page displayed and then I'm out.

This doesn't happen with all applications. I can still load the various settings without problems, Chromium browser works, the terminal works, and so does the file browser. I am sure there are others that work too.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: in case it's related with 3D, try disabling xfce's display composing: (`xfce4-settings-manager` -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Compositor ). If this "solves" it, it would mean it's related to the 3D drivers

Comment: I tried disabling composing, but it did not help. Still the same problem. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I tried to install LXDE, and I have the same problem with LXDE as with xfce. GNOME and KDE work fine.